# SQL Dialect is Not Configured (Phpstorm)

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

I am working on Google oauthorization2 and I encounter problem that

> SQL dialect is not configured

That's why my query is not executing and data is going to table.

I have listed below both of queries where I encounter problem.

Tools:
PhpStorm 8+
MySQL
Localhost

```
$user_exist = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(google_id) as usercount FROM google_users WHERE google_id=$user_id")->fetch_object()->usercount;

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO google_users (google_id, google_name, google_email, google_link, google_picture_link)
        VALUES ($user_id, '$user_name','$email','$profile_url','$profile_image_url')");
```

Comment: I'm having the self same problem, and the ["Data Sources and Drivers dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-a-db-data-source.html) is where the magic is supposed to happen, but it isn't. Perhaps you might have more luck than me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with phpstorm 9.02.  looks like a bug

Comment: To disable the inspection for the next line: `/** @noinspection SqlDialectInspection */`.

Answer (score 133):

Head to `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > SQL Dialects` and set it for the whole project.

Comment: For Mac Version: PhpStorm > Languages & Frameworks > SQL Dialects

Comment: What to you mean by "set it for the whole project"?

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu to select your project's topmost folder and set the dialect there.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu to change SQL dialect PhpStorm uses for a file, a directory, or the entire project, click an item and then choose a dialect from a drop down list.

Answer (score 81):

This is a screenshot of how to do that inside the settings: 
[image]

This is on version 2016.3

Comment: very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! you just saved me!

Comment: Works for PyCharm and I guess for any IntelliJ derivative as well