# PhpStorm: Annoying underline in my DQL statement

Tags: php, phpstorm, dql

I had an issue with PhpStorm that **SQL dialect is not configured** and I tried to solve it as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411778/sql-dialect-is-not-configured-phpstorm) but I encounter another problem with a red line under **AppBundle:Device colon**

[image] in my query says :

> `<form alias definition>, <index hint option>, CROSS, FOR, GROUP, HAVING, INNER, INTO, JOIN, LEFT, LIMIT, LOCK, NATURAL, ORDER, PARTITION, PROCEDURE, RIGHT, STRAIGHT_JOIN, UNION or WHERE expected, got ':'`

This is my code:

```
return $this
->getEntityManager()
->createQuery(
    'SELECT d
    FROM AppBundle:Device d 
    WHERE d.deviceId = :device_id 
    AND d.user_id = :user_id'
)->setParameter('device_id', $deviceId)
->setParameter('user_id', $userId)
->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And it does not throw error that not all params are binded? Shouldn't `:Device` be prepared statement param?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way or a plugin to configure SQL Dialects as DQL in PhpStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440447/is-there-a-way-or-a-plugin-to-configure-sql-dialects-as-dql-in-phpstorm)

Comment: no, it's not throwing an error. note that the query was working before configuring SQL Dialect @Justinas

Comment: Symfony's `DQL` is not `SQL`. Configuring a SQL dialect doesn't help.

Comment: Other option: do not set any SQL Dialect and just disable all SQL inspections: no syntax highlighting, no syntax checking -- no errors reported.

Comment: if you hover over the red line, what is the message that PHPStorm gives?

Comment: it gives me :
<form alias definition>, <index hint option>, CROSS, FOR, GROUP, HAVING, INNER, INTO, JOIN, LEFT, LIMIT, LOCK, NATURAL, ORDER, PARTITION, PROCEDURE, RIGHT, STRAIGHT_JOIN, UNION or WHERE expected, got ':'

@WilliamPerron

Comment: @BaDrAmer You're trying to enter a native SQL inside of Doctrine, you'll need to convert that query to a DQL statement